# Generated password using angular js not working

Tags: angularjs, passwords

I want to make the password is auto generated and to pass it to the controller :

this is my view.jsp:

```
<tr>
                <td class="leftDetails">Password</td>
                <td class="rightDetails"><input type="text" name="password" ng-model="newUser.password" ng-disabled="isEditMode" id="p"/></td>
                <td class="rightDetails"><input type='button' value ='generate' onclick='document.getElementById("p").value = Password.generate(16)' ng-show="add"></td>
                <td class="leftDetails"></td>
                <td class="rightDetails"></td>
            </tr>
  <script>
var Password = {

      _pattern : /[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\+\.]/,


      _getRandomByte : function()
      {
        if(window.crypto && window.crypto.getRandomValues) 
        {
          var result = new Uint8Array(1);
          window.crypto.getRandomValues(result);
          return result[0];
        }
        else if(window.msCrypto && window.msCrypto.getRandomValues) 
        {
          var result = new Uint8Array(1);
          window.msCrypto.getRandomValues(result);
          return result[0];
        }
        else
        {
          return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        }
      },

      generate : function(length)
      {
        return Array.apply(null, {'length': length})
          .map(function()
          {
            var result;
            while(true) 
            {
              result = String.fromCharCode(this._getRandomByte());
              if(this._pattern.test(result))
              {
                return result;
              }
            }        
          }, this)
          .join('');  
      }    

    };
```

My problem is want to pass the generated password to my controller ,it was empty
How to correct that. thanks in advance?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't generating the password in your controller? This is a very non-angular way of doing this. On your button you can use `ng-click` and call the password function in your controller, than you can save it to any variable you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The angular way to solve this issue is to update your input ng-model instead of selecting the element (Jquery way).

Instead of `onClick` use `ng-click="newUser.password = Password.generate(16)"`